# How to use "FB.Canvas.setAutoResize" with the php SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to make the scrollbars in my iFrame application disapear. So I checked the "Auto-resize" radio button under "Facebook Integration" and I understand I need to call "setAutoResize" so the canvas will grow to the height of my page.

But I can't find any documentation about the php SDK or explanation of how and where shall I call this function (and on what object). I can only find relevent documentation abput the JS SDK which is very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do that with PHP SDk (i think)
You should use the magic javascript provided by Facebook in order to resize according to the contents :

```
<div id="FB_HiddenIFrameContainer" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:-100px; top:-100px; width:0px; height: 0px;">
</div> 
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil"], function(){ FB.XdComm.Server.init("xd_receiver.htm"); 
    FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); }); 
</script>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent

Comment: Why won't I be able to? Then what good is the php SDK?

Does it matter where I place this?

Comment: PHP Sdk is to query the Graph API in a more OO/clean way.
This is something about styling and javascript.
You can place it at the bottom of your page.

Comment: @Gal Miller the PHP SDK executes server side and the JavaScript executes client side. Since the iFrame can't be scaled server side (it is being adjusted to fit into the frame) it has to be done client side. Both the PHP and the JavaScript have their usage cases and neither replaces the other as they attack separate problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'your apikey', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil"], function(){ FB.XdComm.Server.init("xd_receiver.htm");
                FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); });
               FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(true,500);
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**FB.Canvas.setAutoResize** function will be removed on January 1st, 2012 as announced in [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/565/). Please use **FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow** instead.

You can read more about [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize/).

**FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow** (Working perfect!)

Note: this method is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Settable (Default: 800px)" in the Developer App.

Starts or stops a timer which will grow your iframe to fit the content every few milliseconds. Default timeout is 100ms.

**Examples**

This function is useful if you know your content will change size, but you don't know when. There will be a slight delay, so if you know when your content changes size, you should call setSize yourself (and save your user's CPU cycles).

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
```

If you ever need to stop the timer, just pass false.

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(false);
```

If you want the timer to run at a different interval, you can do that too.

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(91); // Paul's favourite number
```

Note: If there is only 1 parameter and it is a number, it is assumed to be the interval.

Comment: Please correct your answer. I think you ment FB.Canvas.setAutoResize in the first line...

Comment: thx =) i was really tired that night trying to figure out that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with **FB_HiddenIFrameContainer** doesn't work for me. Try http://fbforce.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-fbcanvassetautoresize.html. This works.

```
 <body style="overflow: hidden">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    };
    (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>

  <div style="height:2000px; width:500px; background:blue;">
   test page
  </div> 
 </body>
```